# MVC DropDownList selection changed not firing Ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am new to mvc and have been doing lots of looking, but I can't figure out why this isn't working.

I have the following View code:

```
$(function() {
    $("#ddlNumberOfRecords").change(function() {

        var numberOfRecords = $("#ddlNumberOfRecords").val();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '@Url.Action("NumberOfRecordsChanged")',
            data: { numberOfRecords: numberOfRecords },
            success: function(returndata) {
                if (!returndata.ok) {
                    window.alert(' error : ' + returndata.message);
                } else {
                    $('#Grid').html(returndata);
                }
            }
        });
    });
});

@Html.DropDownList("ddlNumberOfRecords", Model.NumberOfRecordsSelectList)
```

Can someone tell me what is wrong with that? Also, is there a way to debug that javascript? I put breakpoints on there, but they never load.

EDIT: This is my Action. There is no real content yet because I am just trying to get it to work at this point. But I have a breakpoint and it never gets hit.

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult NumberOfRecordsChanged(int numberOfRecords)
    {
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: All the code you have posted looks fine. Have you used your browser's developer tools to see if the AJAX call is even being sent or that the event is getting wired up correctly?

Comment: I haven't. How do I do that in Chrome? I hit F12, but what am I looking for in there?

Comment: Check the network section to see the AJAX request and see the response from the server and the js console for errors.

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined on line 45. Which is the $(function() { line.

Comment: You are not including jQuery on your page or you have it included multiple times

Comment: Now I'm getting this:Failed to load resource: http://localhost:52822/Home/NumberOfRecordsChanged
the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: Post the whole 500 error message in the original question. It should have a bunch of details and a call stack

Comment: It was a null reference on the DD selected Value. Not sure why that's null, but that's for another time. THanks.

Comment: with your listitem collection did you provide a value?

Comment: I figured it out. First issue was lack of jQuery script reference. 2nd issue was another contributor gave an answer to use some JSon helper method and that was messing things up. I have it working now.

Answer (score 0):

With everything you shown the code works 100%. I made a mock up to prove just that.

**Controller**

```
 public ActionResult Index()
        {
            ViewModel model = new ViewModel
            {
                NumberOfRecordsSelectList = new List<SelectListItem>
                {
                   new SelectListItem
                   {
                       Selected = false,
                       Text = "one",
                       Value = "1",
                   },
                    new SelectListItem
                   {
                       Selected = false,
                       Text = "two",
                       Value = "2",
                   },
                }
            };

            return View(model);
        }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult NumberOfRecordsChanged(int numberOfRecords)
    {
        return null;
    }
```

**View**

```
@model MvcApplication1.Models.ViewModel
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $("#ddlNumberOfRecords").change(function() {

            var numberOfRecords = $("#ddlNumberOfRecords").val();

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '@Url.Action("NumberOfRecordsChanged")',
                data: { numberOfRecords: numberOfRecords },
                success: function (returndata) {
                    //No return data proviced 
                    //if (!returndata.ok) {
                    //    window.alert(' error : ' + returndata.message);
                    //} else {
                    //    $('#Grid').html(returndata);
                    //}
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
@Html.DropDownList("ddlNumberOfRecords", Model.NumberOfRecordsSelectList)
```

If you are getting another error than please share how you are creating your list items, what the error is, and any other details relevant to the problem. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

It seems you're trying to pass over the **number of items in the dropdown** but are in fact sending over the **selected item's value**.

If so, this...

```
var numberOfRecords = $("#ddlNumberOfRecords").val();
```

Should be this...

```
var numberOfRecords = $("#ddlNumberOfRecords option").size();
```

Comment: Nah. I want the selected value of the drop down.